# Determining employment end date on resume

Tags: united-kingdom, employment-gaps

On 1/17, I was told in writing by my last employer that my job has ended today but I am entitled to payment in lieu of notice for the next 6 months, and so I was kept on the payroll from 1/17 to 4/24.

On 4/25, I started a new job.

I have a P45 from my previous employer showing the termination date as 4/24.

Which ending date should I use for my job on my resume, 1/17 or 4/24?

I want to reduce the gap in unemployment on the resume as much as possible without "fudging" or being labeled dishonest.

Comment: it depends if you want to show your actual experience or not.

Comment: For those of us not familiar with the UK job market: What is a P45?

Comment: @Maybe_Factor my answer provides a link to it

Answer (score 11):

The P45 is given when you [stop working](https://www.gov.uk/paye-forms-p45-p60-p11d) for an employer. It's the official (legal) form given and it helps calculate the tax you have paid so far so it can resume properly on the job switch.

**If you have such legal document indicating date 4/24 I suggest you use that date**. IANAL, but technically speaking you were *still* on payroll until that day, so I doubt you were "unemployed" during that period.

Answer (score 2):

> Which ending date should I use for my job on my resume, 1/17 or 4/24?

If you were on payroll until April, then technically you were employed until April. A period of 3 months is not significant enough to worry about, and becomes less significant as your overall job history grows.

> I want to reduce the gap in unemployment on the resume as much as possible without "fudging" or being labeled dishonest.

It's not dishonest -- your resume is not a legal document, just a summary of your employment. Many people only list month and year, and for older jobs, only the years worked. If this were my resume, I would list April 2018 as both the end date of my previous job, and the start date of my current job.