# What month and year should I write in my cv for a job from which I was fired just after a long vacation?

Tags: resume, notice-period, layoff

I started the job as a Java Software Engineer in 09-2022. I worked until the end of 04-2023. Then I took a vacation lasting 3 months, until the beginning of 08-2023. Just after I came back to the workplace, my boss told me I'm fired. Because of the law, the construction of the agreement, and notice period of 1 month, the end of the job relation is the end of 09-2023 and it is written so in the agreement termination. However, I'm not providing any services at all until the termination date.

What month should I use as the end of the job period in my cv and sites like LinkedIn? As of the middle of 08-2023, it's still current job on LinkedIn without any end date right now as I didn't expect such an outcome. Should I use 04-2023 or 09-2023 as the end date of the job period?

Comment: similar case here, but only 3 months, not 5: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113560/determining-employment-end-date-on-resume

Comment: Use your free time from now till 9-2023 to search for a new job.

Comment: Were they very generous in giving you 3 months of vacations, or did they let you gracely took holidays because there was not enough work?

Comment: Most resumes I've seen (and written) just have the years worked, they don't specify months at all.

Comment: @EarlGrey there was a lot to work on, so it wasn't the reason. I wouldn't say they were very generous, my contract was B2B, which means I owned my own one person company and provided services. When I took vacations, I froze the company and didn't provide services. The employer paid partially for my medical cover abroad, but didn't pay salary or anything more than that. So they were generous but not excessively. And it was very stormy time, my ex manager got degraded from the role just a week before I went on vacation.

Comment: @banan314 Wait, so you weren't actually an employee of the company but a contractor? That's a much more important difference than whether you left a few months earlier or later. At least in several EU countries, a setup with a contractor who mostly pretends to be an employee is borderline/outright illegal (because otherwise it would be a simple way to dodge all sorts of labour laws and possibly even evade taxes).

Comment: How much relevant experience did you have before working for that company? I'd be unhappy hiring somebody who claimed a year's worth of on-the-job Java experience if in practice he'd got eight months plus paid time-off in lieu of worked notice. In fact that whole "you're fired and we don't want you back in the building" doesn't sound at all encouraging...

Comment: @TooTea also B2B services would generally be company-to-company confidential by default, and not discussed on LinkedIn unless allowed by contract.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd 1y9m of relevant experience prior the job, so it would be either 2y5m or 2y10m after the most recent position. So it might be a difference of 2 years vs. 3 years in the future, might or might not be significant depending on the view

Comment: I don't understand. Are 3 months of vacations or of unpaid leave?

*So it might be a difference of 2 years vs. 3 years in the future*. The difference is peanuts and not worthwhile the distinction (just think in terms of "I started working in this field as xyz in 2020 ... and keep yourself busy!), unless you are thinking that there is a relevant difference, trying to boast yourself "I worked for 3 years there" and sometime during the next interview your mind+tongue will betray you ;)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Your employment continues, in a legal and financial sense, until September 2023 and so that's the date you should use for your CV. It's also the date that your former employer will confirm if contacted for a reference.

Employment gaps look bad on a CV so there's no reason to prefer the shorter date anyway, even if there were a way to justify it.

Comment: Employment gaps looking bad is subjective. To me they look like someone enjoys time off between work. Travelling maybe, or having a family

Comment: Another way to think about it is if someone wants to know how many months you worked somewhere. If you were employed for 12 months and took 1 month off, nobody would say you'd only been employed for 11 months, regardless of when the month off happened.

Comment: @Craig I doubt that many interviewers, whose job in the process is to find the person(s) likely to help the company most, share your positive view of "enjoys time off and spending time with family" as a character trait.

Comment: @Craig I understand what you're trying to say, but from the perspective of giving someone advice on writing a competitive CV, I don't think 'deliberately try to add employment gaps' is particularly helpful.

Comment: Employment gaps look bad if you are not proactive in describing them. 
Some HR people may be a tad late to the party, but they are learning to ask tactful questions when they see a "gap" in a CV, instead of barelling down with assumptions and unfounded conclusions.

Comment: At least the part of the world i'm in, employment gaps only look bad to people who missed the last, say 5 years, of developments in the job market. Of course it might come up during an interview, but it isn't any form of no go anymore, like it was a couple of years ago.
Honestly, i wouldn't want to work for employers who sort me out due to "evil  employment gaps" anyway. Indicative of toxic hustle culture.

Comment: @Craig are you a hiring manager making decisions based on that opinion? Because otherwise, the statement "Employment gaps look bad on a CV" from the answer still stands.

Comment: Employment gaps look bad precisely to the people who it is convenient for you for them to look bad for. Scrutinising small gaps or selecting based on them is a big red flag of the company's unstated culture.

Comment: An employment gap generally slightly weakens one's negotiating position in many cases.

Comment: The problem with employment gaps at least in the US is that they have many possible explanations from the good (caring for a sick relative) to the bad (can’t find work due to general incompetence, prison stay, uncontrolled mental health problem, drug problem, etc.). If the candidate provides a good explanation in a cover letter that’s fine. But if there’s no cover letter and there’s a multi-year gap, how should the hiring manager proceed with the risk analysis? They have a responsibility not only to find good candidates but to protect their employer from bad ones. Gaps are risks.

Comment: To be clear I don’t think every gap is a worst-case scenario, but hiring isn’t about making friends, it’s about finding the right candidates with almost no information to go by. It’s very hard and very high risk. A bad candidate can cost you a great deal as a company. So as much as you may want to be a nice person and give everyone a chance, at the end of the day you can’t afford to ignore potential red flags when hiring, and long unexplained gaps on the resume, especially a pattern of them, are just that: potential red flags.

Comment: @wimi Yes I am. I run a team of 10 and occasionally sit on interview panels for other teams

Comment: @Dakeyras I didn't advise anyone to "deliberately try to add employment gaps", I just said they don't look bad to everyone