# Should I edit my cv to change end date of employment period if it is incorrect after 1 year

Tags: resume

That is how my cv looks like now:

```
09.2022–08.2023, Company A
01.2022–05.2022, Company B
```

I was fired from Company B on May 24, 2022, and they took my laptop the same day and I didn't work for them anymore. However, they paid me salary for 05.2022 and 06.2022 because of the European law and 1 month notice period. [Given answer to that question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/192819/what-month-and-year-should-i-write-in-my-cv-for-a-job-i-was-fired-just-after-a-l/192821#192821), I should have written the end month of the employment period for company B in cv as 06.2022, not 05.2022, but I wasn't aware that this is the best approach. So it should look like

```
09.2022–08.2023, Company A
01.2022–06.2022, Company B
```

Today is 08.2023, over a year after the employment for company B ended. Should I amend the employment end date now in cv, LinkedIn, and various recruitment sites where I have sent that information already months ago?

If so, should I write something about this amendment, that I'm sorry for the misunderstanding and I'm amending the resume because of my previous mistake?

Comment: These things don't matter as much as you probably think they do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, go ahead and amend the date in all your documents and sites. Now that you know it had a minor mistake it would not make sense nor be positive for you to leave it.

I don't think there is a need to "explain" or justify such amend, it's a minor fix/correction anybody should see the reason behind doing that; just do it.

Edit your CV and be sure to send that in future applications. Edit you Linkedin info accordingly. Send or update CV/dates on your other sites.